# Use of CachingAuthenticator in Dropwizard

Tags: java, dropwizard

I want to discard old authentications from dropwizard, which is why I'm using blow configuration of CachingAuthenticator.

```
@Override 
public void run(WebConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) {
   environment.jersey().register(new ActivityResource());
    
   CachingAuthenticator<BasicCredentials, AuthUser> cachingAuthenticator =
        new CachingAuthenticator<>(environment.metrics(), new WebAuthenticator(), 
                configuration.getAuthenticationCachePolicy());
}
```

Policy is in yml file as

```
authenticationCachePolicy: maximumSize=10, expireAfterAccess=1m
```

My questions are:

1. how do I register(get it working) cachingAuthenticator so every request will be authenticated?
2. How to set expireAfterAccess in seconds?
3. Anything which is wrong in code, please suggest...

Comment: 2.) I think it is a dropwizard duration so you can do this:expireAfterAccess=15seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working solution

```
/** authentication config */
CachingAuthenticator<BasicCredentials, AuthUser> cachingAuthenticator = new CachingAuthenticator<>(
    environment.metrics(), new MyAuthenticator(), configuration.getAuthenticationCachePolicy());

environment.jersey().register(new AuthDynamicFeature(new BasicCredentialAuthFilter.Builder<AuthUser>()
    .setAuthenticator(cachingAuthenticator).setRealm("kedar.javalkar.realm").buildAuthFilter()));

environment.jersey().register(new AuthValueFactoryProvider.Binder<>(AuthUser.class));
```

The yml can either have

```
# Caching authenticator.
authenticationCachePolicy: maximumSize=10000, expireAfterAccess=10m
```

or

```
# Caching authenticator.
authenticationCachePolicy: maximumSize=10000, expireAfterAccess=1s
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about about "2)" but for "1)", you simply need to wire the authenticator up to the Basic auth provider

```
CachingAuthenticator<BasicCredentials, AuthUser> cachingAuthenticator =
        new CachingAuthenticator<>(environment.metrics(), new WebAuthenticator(), 
                configuration.getAuthenticationCachePolicy());

environment.jersey().register(AuthFactory.binder(
            new BasicAuthFactory<>(cachingAuthenticator,
                     "Example Realm", AuthUser.class)));
```

Comment: Thanks... i ran a small test on browser, resulting only on valid credentials provided. I can be wrong but how does caching authenticator work ? how do i test that credentials are actually removed bcos my browser results even after i hit the request 10 mins later

Comment: You can put a print statement in your authenticator. The authenticator is called if the there is no credentials in the cache. As for the browser, it might cache the request and send it with each request. Not sure exactly how it works. That usually happens with Basic auth I don't know why. But with Basic auth, you need to authenticate for each request. The purpose of the cache is just to avoid having to hit the db again. It has nothing to do with holding any kind of client session. You might want to test with a different client, like cURL to see the effect